# How to set mapbox static map marker offset?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-static-maps

If marker shape is a drop we need to set it's offset, there is no sense setting anchor point to center for eccentric markers.

I can't find any options to control mapbox static image map marker offset in mapbox API.
[enter link description here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#marker)

The only idea comes to my head is detecting lng/lat with some offset.
For example we can initialize hidden mapbox-gl-js map 100px/100px sized and use project->update pixels offset->unproject to get lng lat back, or somehow else.

Comment: You wouldn't need to initialise a map you could just use the spherical Mercator projection library directly. Search on the Mapbox GitHub account and there should be one there.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pad your marker image with white space so the tip is at the image centre.